# Arrow symbol for chemical equation

Tags: html, css, mathml

I need to reproduce the following arrow symbol for a chemical reaction

[image]

I tried something like this:

⟶<sup>1. BH<sub>3</sub></sup><sub>2) H<sub>2</sub>O2</sub>, NaOH

but it doesn't look good. I'd like to avoid images for such a small amount of text and use only HTML/CSS or if applicable MathML.

Comment: Use mathml. It provides everything you need